# Parshin's buildings for higher local fields

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, local-fields, buildings

What is the status of the theory of buildings for higher local fields?

I know that there are some papers of Parshin, in which he describes some examples, like $PGL_2$ and $PGL_3$ over two-dimensional local fields. Parshin also mentions a definition of buildings, due to Ginzburg and Kapranov, for reductive groups over two-dimensional local fields, and says that the two definitions do not agree in general. That's about all the papers I know in this direction.

So I was wondering: Is there a general definition of buildings for reductive groups over higher local fields? If there are several definitions, is their relation known? Are there any introductory articles on buildings over higher local fields that I could read? How much of the theory of spherical or euclidean buildings (BN-pair theory, metric aspects, simplicial aspects) has been generalized? But most importantly: are there any theorems that have been proved using this theory? Maybe something in the direction of representation theory?